# Mocking new HttpClientErrorException.NotFound

Tags: java, rest, junit, mockito, http-status-code-404

I have a third party service that returns `HttpClientErrorException.NotFound`. When it returns this exception, I throw the exception from my application saying the input is invalid but for all other exceptions like service unavailable and all, I need to use a default value and proceed further.

My code block is as below:

```
public String callService(String input)
    {
        String value = "";
        try
        {
            value = service.callMethod(input);
        }
        catch(HttpClientErrorException.NotFound e1)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Invalid Input")
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            value = "US";
        }
        return value;
    }
```

When I am writing JUnit for this, how do I mock the call for service.callMethod(input) and return `HttpClientErrorException.NotFound`?

I tried mocking and sending the status code as below but it does not work.

Junit Test case method is as below:

```
@Test(expected = ApplicationException.class)
public void callServiceInvalidInput() throws ApplicationException 
{
    String inputValue = "JLR";
    when(externalService.callMethod(inputValue))        
    .thenThrow(new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    
    String result = handler.callService(inputValue);
}
```

When I mock the service call, the catch clause that gets executed is Exception e and not the previous one. The reason is object e is instanceof HttpClientErrorException when mocked; but when the actual service call happens, it is instance of HttpClientErrorException$NotFound

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work exactly? are you getting any error?

Comment: You cannot mock a private method response with mockito. Try using powermock or easymock.

Comment: Explain your problem in a better way or do change when(xyz.callService(`anyString())`).thenThrow(.....) and try. xyz is a mock instance of the class.

Comment: @dhruvtailor : It was by mistake, I corrected the access modifier.

Comment: When I mock the service call, the catch clause that gets executed is Exception e and not the previous one. The reason is object e is instanceof HttpClientErrorException when mocked; but when the actual service call happens, it is instance of HttpClientErrorException$NotFound

Comment: If you are mocking callService() the exception you need to throw is `ApplicationException`.

Comment: Please show the complete code you are actually using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer when I tried to check how the NotFound is actually set.

```
when(externalService.callMethod(inputValue)) 
.thenThrow(HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "not found", null, null, null));
```

I called the create method to return that particular inner class.